# Why in first case program is working without '*' but in another it instant crash

Tags: c, dynamic-tables

I have weird problem. I don't understand why my program in this case is working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void wielkosc(int *tab, int size)
{
    tab = malloc(size + sizeof(int)); // here is located the problem. I know I am missing '*'
}
void wstaw(int *tab, int size)
{
    printf("Numbers in : \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    {
        scanf("%d",tab + i);
    }

}
int policz(int *tab, int size)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    {
        result += *(tab + i);
    }


    return result;
}
void wypisz(int result)
{
    printf("Result: %d",result);
}
int main()
{
    int *tab;
    int size;
    printf("Size: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    void (*array_size)(int *, int) = wielkosc;
    void (*array_put)(int *, int) = wstaw;
    int (*array_calc)(int *, int) = policz;
    void (*get_result)(int) = wypisz;
    array_size(&tab, size);
    array_put(tab, size);
    int result = array_calc(tab, size);
    get_result(result);
}
```

But if I will remove 2 last lines int result and get_result it will instantly crash.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void wielkosc(int *tab, int size)
{
    tab = malloc(size + sizeof(int));
}
void wstaw(int *tab, int size)
{
    printf("Numbers in : \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    {
        scanf("%d",tab + i);
    }

}
int policz(int *tab, int size)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    {
        result += *(tab + i);
    }


    return result;
}
void wypisz(int result)
{
    printf("Result: %d",result);
}
int main()
{
    int *tab;
    int size;
    printf("Size: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    void (*array_size)(int *, int) = wielkosc;
    void (*array_put)(int *, int) = wstaw;
    int (*array_calc)(int *, int) = policz;
    void (*get_result)(int) = wypisz;
    array_size(&tab, size);
}
```

I know I am missing "*" before tab on the start in "void wielkosc" but I have no idea why program in first case let me put all numbers and works fine but without 2 last voids it let me put only 1 number and after that it crashes.

Comment: *"is working"* and *"instantly crash"* can both be (in your case, both are) some manifestation of **Undefined Behaviour** ==> `array_size(&tab, size);` has wrong 1st argument

Comment: In wielkosc you call malloc but don't return a pointer to the memory.

Comment: Note that the second example omits three lines, not just two.